# Show heroku app logs in the browser in real time

Tags: heroku

I can do Heroku logs -tail --app myapp and see what goes on when things happen in the app.

Would there be a way to show the output of logs -tail **in the browser** in real time just like I can do with the Heroku client?

I know it is a strange question, anyone has an idea?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like Papertrail and then a syslog drain to send your heroku logs to them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yeah I then found out about syslog and similar options, sounded like too much worry for the problem. At this point I'm implementing some monitoring via ajax to check the progress of the background processes.

Comment: we use the syslog method extensively - with Papertrail you can conduct live searches of your logs and have the results notified via a POST message - we use this even to scale our applications based on the heroku[router] message in the log. It takes about 10 seconds to setup.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use heroku client library for login and then heroku logs -t as system command to display the output on browser.

```
@heroku = Heroku::Client.new(account.email, account.password)
`heroku logs -t `
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Looks interesting. I will try it out and vote for the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

heroku logs --tail is all you need to enter.  I got this from the Heroku documentation.